# Spark Univocity parser - LineSeparatorDetection not working

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, univocity

I am trying to parse [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17il3TI_WGzvPHooTDyc-rF1C2YlNq1SW/view?usp=sharing) csv file using univocity csv parser with the following options

options :

```
HEADER -> true
DELIMITERS -> ,
MULTILINE -> true
DEFAULT_TIME_STAMP -> yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ
IGNORE_TRAILING_WHITE_SPACE -> false
IGNORE_LEADING_WHITE_SPACE -> false
TIME_ZONE -> Asia/Kolkata
COLUMN_PRUNING -> true
ESCAPE -> "\""

val csvOptionsObject = new CSVOptions(readerOptions, COLUMN_PRUNING , TIME_ZONE)
val parserInstance = csvOptionsObject.asParserSettings
parserInstance.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true)
val parserObject = new CsvParser(parserInstance)
val readerStream = parserObject.beginParsing(dataObj.getInputStream, csvOptionsObject.charset)
val row = parserObject.parseNext()
```

The file has 30 columns but when I parse it is showing as 2302 rows.

The file has \r as line separator. (as I can see it while parsing)

Setting the line separator explicitly as \r resolves this issue.
But I will also have files with \n as separator that is replaced as \r.
To resolve this setting `setNormalizedLineEndingWithinQuotes(false)` resolves , but fails with other files where all the values are quoted.(Again fails to detect the separator).

Any possible work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the asParserSettings from spark CSVOptions by default changed the inputBufferSize to 128 (default value in spark) , whereas the default value in univocity csv parser is 1048576.

Adding this code solved the porblem,

```
val csvOptionsObject = new CSVOptions(readerOptions, COLUMN_PRUNING , TIME_ZONE)
val parserInstance = csvOptionsObject.asParserSettings
parserInstance.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true)
parserInstance.setInputBufferSize(1048576) // Setting it to match univocity parser's default value
val parserObject = new CsvParser(parserInstance)
val readerStream = parserObject.beginParsing(dataObj.getInputStream, csvOptionsObject.charset)
val row = parserObject.parseNext()
```